# How to update a disabled mixed index to enabled?

Tags: janusgraph

Now i have an mixed index,it's status is DISABLED like this :

```
gremlin> m.getGraphIndex('singleProperty_mixedIndex').getIndexStatus(m.getPropertyKey('prop1'))
==>DISABLED
```

now i want to update this index's status to ENABLED,how can i to do?

I have tried several times using these gremlin,but it doesn't work:

```
m = graph.openManagement();
i = m.getGraphIndex('singleProperty_mixedIndex');
m.updateIndex(i, SchemaAction.REGISTER_INDEX);
m.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, 'singleProperty_mixedIndex').status(SchemaStatus.INSTALLED).call();
m.commit();
m=graph.openManagement();
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a mixed index or how to update a disabled mixed index to enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47808505/how-to-delete-a-mixed-index-or-how-to-update-a-disabled-mixed-index-to-enabled)

Comment: I have delete another duplicate question! Thx

Comment: This one was the duplicate. You deleted the one with an answer. Oops.

Comment: yes, that one is not important for me . Now I want to know the answer of this   question!  Grateful for your  attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, a disabled index in JanusGraph cannot be re-enabled. Disabling an index is the last step before removing it ([wiki reference](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/wiki/Indexing)). Your options are:

- Remove the index, and then recreate it
- Create an index with a different name, but with the same properties

Comment: Thank you very much for answer my question, but I haven't see any example of remove a JanusGraph mixed index , do i have to delete the mixed index in both cassandra and elasticsearch ? Are there some example  in reference of JanusGraph Documentation? Very grateful for your answer!